# Magento 2 Knockout JS - nested arrays

Tags: magento2, knockoutjs

I've got nested arrays in my config JSON:

Each `Step` node contains own `products` array.

[image]

`Foreach` binding in a template for `steps` array works fine (the `title` value is displayed). However, I can't list `products` array within single `step` node.

Here is my code:

```
<div id="configurator-wrapper" data-bind="scope: 'drago-configurator'">
    <ul data-bind="foreach: steps">
       <li data-bind="text: title">
            <ul data-bind="foreach: products">
                <li data-bind="text: name"></li>
            </ul>
       </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your text binding is overwriting the nested UL, so you'll want to use a separate element. Something like this should work:

```
<div id="configurator-wrapper" data-bind="scope: 'drago-configurator'">
    <ul data-bind="foreach: steps">
       <li>
            <span data-bind="text: title"></span>
            <ul data-bind="foreach: products">
                <li data-bind="text: name"></li>
            </ul>
       </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, of course! Silly me. Thanks Ben.

Comment: @BenCrook sir can you please help me here? https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/295095/68281 It means a lot for me if you solve this.